# Issue sampling my own music into OpenAI's Jukebox using Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, audio, anaconda, openai-universe

I'm having issues importing my own samples into Jukebox (https://github.com/openai/jukebox/) and received this error message when attempting to select my files. "AttributeError: module 'torch.distributed' has no attribute 'ReduceOp'"

Here is a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0cdlpzo3n0u4yg/jukeboxcodeproblem.png?dl=0

Anyone know how to fix this? I've followed all the steps in the readme.md file (https://github.com/openai/jukebox/) up until this point. I'm very new to coding so all help is very appreciated.

Comment: Hi...please post a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have the same issue. From what I got, pytorch.distributed is not supported on Windows: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html

If you try smth like:

```
> python
>>> import torch
>>> import torch.ditributed as dist
>>> dist.is_available()
```

You'll get "False"

A bit more info can be found here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex/issues/429

So, to make it work you need Linux or somehow get rid of torch distributed.

Comment: WSL2 is not an option as well: GPUs are not supported for now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq

Comment: I can confirm now that on Ubuntu it works like a charm.

Comment: Had a quick scroll through that forum you posted and from what I could gather, some people were saying that installing apex from this repository fixes the Pytorch issues with Windows, however, the issue I posted above still persists for me after installing the new version of apex so I'm at a loss. 

Also I tried that code you posted above and got this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4iwn6oltj34lxbp/uhhcode.png

Apologies for my ignorance but I'm still unclear as to what I should do at this point.